# Sqlplus in silent mode is not silent

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I'm using sqlplus in shell script and it works(sqlplus without silent mode) but I can see the output in the terminal. I tried running it in silent mode with different combinations but it didn't work -

```
sqlplus -s "$DBUSER/$DBPWD@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=$DBHOST)(Port=$DBPORT))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=$DBSID)))"  @$SCRHOME/getCsv$sqlFile.sql
```

<Btw the -s is in yellow and not black, like the echo command in a shell script>

It works but I can see the output on console. I also tried:

```
sqlplus \-s "....
sqlplus \-s \ "...
sqplus -S
sqlplus -s \ << EOF "...
```

I tried removing the double quotes, but then in that case even the sqlplus command doesn't work. I'm using this command in a shell script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct format is:

```
sqlplus -S LOGIN_INFO @SCRIPT_TO_RUN
```

The "silent" mode doesn't prevent terminal output.  All it does is:

```
-S             Sets silent mode which suppresses the display of
               the SQL*Plus banner, prompts, and echoing of
               commands.
```

If you want to suppress all terminal output, then you'll need to do something like:
`sqlplus ... > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use set termout off

It would be:

`sqlplus -S "$DBUSER/$DBPWD@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=$DBHOST)(Port=$DBPORT))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=$DBSID)))"  @$SCRHOME/getCsv$sqlFile.sq`l

And add this line at the beginning of the getCsv$sqlFile.sql (it must be before of any sql command).

```
set termout off
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to suppress the terminal output, it is possible by using `spool` in your SQLPlus script and diverting the terminal output to /dev/null. Here's how I did it:

Firstly the SQLPlus:

```
spool ${HOME}/output.dat;
select
... <your query here> ...
;
spool off;
```

Suppose this is placed in the file `$HOME/my.sql`. This could be invoked in a bash script as follows:

```
echo "$(sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF
CONNECT <your DB connnect string>
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
set echo off
@${HOME}/my.sql
exit;
EOF) " > /dev/null
```

The output of the query will be sent to `${HOME}/output.dat` and no SQLPlus output will go to your terminal (or log file as it was in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Unset `ORACLE_PATH` to not execute the content of login.sql

```
then sqlplus -S , or sqlplus -s

[oracle]$ unset ORACLE_PATH
[oracle]$ OUTPUT=$( sqlplus -S / as sysdba <<EOF
> set heading OFF termout ON trimout ON feedback OFF
> set pagesize 0
> select sysdate from dual;
> exit;
> EOF
> )
[oracle]$ echo $OUTPUT
05/09/23
```